# how to get API data inside map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, solver

how do I get the API data here based on the user's choice, for example if the user chooses number 3 then the data that is issued is the data that is at number 3 in the API

```
final List<String> list = <String>['Ganjil', 'Genap'  ]; 

final data = {
  'Ganjil': [
    '1', //I want to call API data here
    '3', //I want to call API data here
    '5', //I want to call API data here
    '7', //I want to call API data here
  ],
  'Genap': [
    '2', //I want to call API data here
    '4', //I want to call API data here
    '6', //I want to call API data here
    '8',
  ],
};
```

> i want to call data based on existing id in API. how do i do it. Thank
> you so when the user selects number 1 it will display API data with ID number 1

```
Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 8),
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                              child: DropdownButton(
                                hint: const Text(
                                  'Pilih Semester',
                                ),
                                isExpanded: true,
                                value: mainValue,
                                items: list
                                    .map(
                                      (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
                                        value: e,
                                        child: Text(
                                          e,
                                          style: regular5,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                    .toList(),
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  subValue = null;
                                  mainValue = value;
                                  setState(() {});
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 16,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Semester',
                            style: bold5,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 8,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 8),
                            width: double.infinity,
                            height: 50,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                              child: DropdownButton(
                                hint: Text(
                                  'Pilih Semester',
                                  style: regular5,
                                ),
                                isExpanded: true,
                                value: subValue,
                                items: data[mainValue]
                                        ?.map(
                                          (e) => DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
                                            value: e,
                                            child: Text(
                                              e,
                                              style: regular5,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        )
                                        .toList() ??
                                    [],
                                onChanged: (value) {
                                  subValue = value.toString();
                                  setState(() {});
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
```

> and this respon json

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "code": "200",
    "data": {
        "1": {
            "id": "f732bbb0-a34a-474d-8829-23aa66470e22",
            "id_dosen": "d6aedfb6-cf88-4e89-8365-0f206822a6c4",
            "id_mk": "cb0bced5-a02d-4f46-bd88-6ed61daece10",
            "nidn": null,
            "dosen": "Yudhy",
            "id_kelas_kuliah": "52deb32d-292f-44b9-af69-a90dfc5fbc81",
            "kelas_kuliah": "Pendidikan agama islam III - Sistem Informasi - A",
            "prodi": "Sistem Informasi",
            "kelas": "KARYAWAN",
            "semester": "5",
            "kelompok_kelas": "A",
            "kode": null,
            "sks": 2,
            "jumlah_kelas": 0,
            "matakuliah": "Pendidikan agama islam III ( Islamic Religious Education III ) - A",
            "smt": "2022-2023 GANJIL",
            "bobot_sks": 2,
            "rencana_pertemuan": 14,
            "jenis_evaluasi": "KOGNITIF/PENGETAHUAN",
            "created_at": "2022-09-09 08:14:14",
            "updated_at": "2022-09-09 08:14:14",
            "created_by": "Fahmi Nugraha",
            "updated_by": "Fahmi Nugraha"
        },
        "2": {
            "id": "3573bcf8-bf00-445b-91bb-8362e98f3e70",
            "id_dosen": "d61b7164-cd6c-4bd9-8be8-d2a576790b9c",
            "id_mk": "40f02349-887d-47c2-b190-9c5d62adf738",
            "nidn": null,
            "dosen": "Shadam Hussaeni",
            "id_kelas_kuliah": "fb969bb3-e0d9-47ac-9ede-365c78e38994",
            "kelas_kuliah": "Bahasa inggris III (Conversation) - Sistem Informasi - A",
            "prodi": "Sistem Informasi",
            "kelas": "KARYAWAN",
            "semester": "5",
            "kelompok_kelas": "A",
            "kode": null,
            "sks": 2,
            "jumlah_kelas": 0,
            "matakuliah": "Bahasa inggris III (Conversation) ( English III (Conversation) ) - A",
            "smt": "2022-2023 GANJIL",
            "bobot_sks": 2,
            "rencana_pertemuan": 14,
            "jenis_evaluasi": "KOGNITIF/PENGETAHUAN",
            "created_at": "2022-09-14 08:05:31",
            "updated_at": "2022-09-14 08:05:31",
            "created_by": "Risca Nurzantika",
            "updated_by": "Risca Nurzantika"
        }, ...
```

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't clear enough. Try to add more details.

Comment: I update for the question

Comment: So you want to fetch a certain data for "4" since it's selected?

Comment: yes, I want to get data based on user's choice

Comment: So Sharon. Kindly add where you implemented your "onchange" method in your Dropdown/PopupMenuItem widget to the question

Comment: I have updated, sorry if my question is incomplete

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249606/discussion-between-theodore-and-sharon).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the API in onChange with the new mainValue

```
onChanged: (value) {
   subValue = value.toString();

   callAPI(); // Call API here

   setState(() {});
}
```

Comment: how to get value in json ex: id, id_dosen, kelas etc